# How to bring back older version of mesa packages from ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

Tags: apt, xorg, ppa, mesa

I'm trying to install older version of mesa packages from xorg-edgers PPA using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty mesa-common-dev=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libgl1-mesa-dri:i386=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libgl1-mesa-glx:i386=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libosmesa6:i386=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libosmesa6:amd64=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libgles2-mesa-dev=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libgles2-mesa:amd64=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libglapi-mesa:amd64=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libglapi-mesa:i386=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libopenvg1-mesa:amd64=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty libegl1-mesa:amd64=10.3.0~git20140812.fa5b76e3-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty
```

Unfortunately I receive that there is no such a version for each package.. Could you please verify if I put it in wrong format or the packages no longer exist?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, version 10.3.0 is no longer available on their ppa repository.

You can always check similar thing:

1. Go back to PPA page on developer/team profile

   https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers
2. Choose the correct ppa:

   [xorg-edgers fresh X crack](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
3. Click on *Technical details about this PPA* → then follow link

   ```
   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
   deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
   ```
4. Let's look for `mesa-common-dev`, go to `pool/main/m/mesa/`

Or you may compose it:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/

`http://ppa.launchpad.net/<developer-or-team-name>/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/<1st-letter-of-package-name-prefixed-with-lib-if-it's>/<source-package-name>/`